# Manipulation with date functions in makumba

Tags: makumba

trying out date functions. Want to list posts only 10 days old, older than that, I won't show. I have this query:

dayOfYear($now)-dayOfYear(p.TS_create)<10 and year($now)=year(p.TS_create)

inside of:

`<mak:list from="general.forum.Post p" where="dayOfYear($now)-dayOfYear(p.TS_create)<10 and year($now)=year(p.TS_create)">`

It works, but just want to ask if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: This would fail on Jan 1st 2012, for values such as Dec 25th, 2011! Handle the wrap-around scenarios too...

Answer (score 1):

Well this is probably not the best option.

First of all `year($now)=year(p.TS_create)` will result that on the 1st of Jan you would not see the posts from the last 9 days of the previous years (which I guess you would want to see also).

Otherwise, the `dayOfYear()` would probably work, but since it represents a day in a year (and not total number of days since min date possible) the better option would be to use something like:

```
dateAdd(p.TS_create, 10, 'day') > now()
```

P.S. Also have in mind that if you use `$now` you have to set it as context attribute, however inside MQL you have a function `now()` which you can use instead. So if you're not using `$now` in other places in the page (like in `c:if` statements) it's better to use the function.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the numerical representation of dates in milliseconds, as in the following:

```
unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(p.TS_create) < 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

(10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 equals to 10 days)

mind that both solutions (using millisecond or dateAdd(p.TS_create, 10, 'day') > now()) will actually compare 240 hours, and disregard calendar days.